# ValueError could not convert string to float: is IterativeImputer in sklearn only for numerical features?

Tags: python, scikit-learn

I have a data frame that has this kind of data in it:

```
ID      category
ID2     category
Sex     category
Cysts   category
Death   category
Years   int64
Group   category
```

An example of the data:

```
0    11090    1  0  0  0  46  1
1    10336    5  0  0  1  60  2
2     8117    8  1  0  1  39  1
3    10262    9  0  0  1  37  5
4    11084   10  0  0  1  47  1
```

There are 15 missing entries in column 'Cysts' that I want to impute.

When I write this code for SimpleImputer:

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('filtered.txt',sep='\t',dtype='category').iloc[:,:7]
print(df.dtypes)
imp = SimpleImputer(missing_values='-1',strategy='most_frequent')
df = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df))
print(df)
```

it prints an output as expected:

```
..     ...  ... .. .. ..  .. ..
209  10373  164  1  1  0  44  1
210  11267  171  1  1  0  81  6
211  11101  175  1  1  1  65  1
212  11232  176  1  1  0  28  1
213  11236  176  1  1  0  31  1
```

(i.e. the -1s that were originally in this column as missing data are replaced with 1s in column 4).

```
import pandas as pd
import scipy.sparse as sp
from sklearn.impute import SimpleImputer
from sklearn.experimental import enable_iterative_imputer
from sklearn.impute import IterativeImputer
import numpy as np

df = pd.read_csv('filtered.txt',sep='\t',dtype='category').iloc[:,:7]
print(df.dtypes)
imp = IterativeImputer(missing_values='-1',initial_strategy='most_frequent')
df = pd.DataFrame(imp.fit_transform(df))
print(df)
```

But I get the error:

```
ValueError: could not convert string to float: '8127/10206'
```

That value is one of the values in the ID2 column, I'm aware it's not a float, it's not meant to be.

Can the iterative imputer only be used with numeric columns?  I thought by having a 'most_frequent' initial_strategy parameter that categorical data could be used, but maybe I'm wrong?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

`IterativeImputer` uses an `Estimator` object (Bayesian Ridge regression by default) to iteratively make better predictions for each column's missing values using the values of the other columns as features. It does not support non-numeric data. You may be able to get acceptable results if you cast the data to numeric, iteratively impute, then re-discretize it .

I have not tested this, but you may be able to one-hot encode strictly categorical data and iteratively impute it with a `Classifier`.